# Different results in DES-CBC algorithm implementation from PHP to node.js

Tags: php, node.js, cryptojs, encryption-symmetric

I have the following code in PHP

```
        if (!$string) {
            return false;
        }
            $method = 'DES-CBC';
            $key = base64_decode("key.."); // 56 bits key for DES-CBC
            if (in_array($method, openssl_get_cipher_methods())) {
                return @openssl_encrypt($string . "\0", $method, $key, null, null);
            }
        return false;
```

For example, when I run this code with test@test.com the output is 9z7664djEMCN79LeMUGMVQ==

In node.js I don't find a way to encrypt DES-CBC algorithm with no IV

my node code:

```
const algorithm = 'des-cbc';
const key = Buffer.from('key..', 'base64');
const iv = new Buffer(8); // 8 byte buffer
iv.fill(0); // fill with zeros

const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(algorithm, key, null);
let encrypted = cipher.update('test@test.com0', 'utf8', 'base64');
encrypted += cipher.final('base64');
console.log('Encrypted: ', encrypted);
```

but I get different results:
9z7664djEMAZTZOO7vNY3g== in node js vs 9z7664djEMCN79LeMUGMVQ== in PHP

Comment: by mistake, sorry removing it

Comment: Did you test your node function with an IV of 8 x0 bytes (not using the "null" value) ?

Comment: @MichaelFehr thanks, it did help, now I don't get the error but get a different encrypted key